# Rpi 3 model B+ USB enable pin

Tags: usb, reset

I am using USB 3G modem with my RPi 3 modem B+. Modem gets freeze sometimes so i need to reset it. I was using 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line
but it can't reset my modem. As i know Rpi3 uses AP2552 for USB power. AP2552 has a enable pin, which pin of BCM controls that enable? How i control that pin?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this through GPIO. But IIRC it still may be possible through other means. Have never tried it myself but https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=196827 or https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=203261 could be a start

Comment: I found "echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind" but it power down all  USBs and ethernet also. I tried "echo '1-1.1.3' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind" for my specific USB port but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can manipulate individual ports. And it would probably the same if you could manipulate the AP2552 since onboard ethernet uses USB

Comment: Yes, it is like that. I have tested it, it is impossible to power off either USB ports individually or just all USB ports without ethernet.